# Using @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) in populated database causes PK constraint error

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to add `FeedbackItem` items to my database. The general idea is that an existing object of type `Group` can receive multiple `FeedbackItem` objects. Afterwards I update the object:

```
groupDAO.startTransaction();
groupDAO.update(selectedGroup);
groupDAO.commitTransaction();

//in groupDAO
public T update(T entity){
   return em.merge(entity);
}
```

I'm not suring whether it is JPA causing the issue or not, but the following error will appear:

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL170430012202680' defined on 'FEEDBACKITEM'.

After some more debugging I found the following entries:

> [EL Fine]: sql: 2017-04-30 01:22:14.977-- #### VALUES (?, ?) bind =>
>   [sampleText, 2]
>
> [EL Fine]: sql: 2017-04-30
>   01:22:14.997--ClientSession(889348271)--Thread(Thread[JavaFX
>   Application Thread,5,main])--VALUES(1)

Does `VALUES(1)` mean that it's trying to insert the object under the ID 1? It's the only lead I currently have. My database is populated with 10 entries, having an ID ranging from 1 to 10.

Below is the class I'm trying to persist to the database:

```
@Entity
public class FeedbackItem implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int feedbackId;

    private String feedback;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private User ownerFeedback;

    protected FeedbackItem(){

    }
}
```

I tested my code without `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` and assigned ID's manually. This works without any issues.

**EDIT:** below is the `Group` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Group implements IReadOnlyGroup {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int groupId;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    private List<Action> actions;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Proposal> proposals;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    private List<Motivation> motivations;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "group")
    private GroupState currentState;

    public Groep() {
    }
}
```

The `Group` object contains the `FeedbackItem` objects indirectely. Each `Proposal` stores one `FeedbackItem`

```
Entity
public class Proposal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date = null;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Action> actions;

    @OneToOne
    private FeedbackItem feedbackitem;

    boolean approved;

    protected Proposal() {

    }

    public Proposal ( List<Action> actions, String feedback, boolean approved, User owner){
        this.date = new Date();
        this.actions = actions;
        this.approved = approved;
        this.feedbackitem = new FeedBackItem(feedback, owner);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `groupDAO.update()` do?

Comment: The update method contains an `EntityManager` merge.
I added the code to the question.

Comment: @Tumladhir paste code for Group entity.

Comment: How did you populate those 10 items in your DB, and how did you setup the identity sequence?  What database and database platform is set?  EclipseLink will not pass in a value for the ID when using identity on supported platforms, so either it isn't set up correctly, or you are passing in an entity with a value already set.  Logging should show the full SQL being used, including the list of values passed in for the statement that is causing the error, so you can check how the value in question was assigned or if you passed in an entity with this value and didn't correctly call merge on it

Comment: The items were inserted using `insert into` statements. I did not set up any explicit identity sequence. I'm using JDBC derby with EclipseLink JPA 2.1 .
The query in the log file (trying to persist a new object while working in the application) is the following: `INSERT INTO FEEDBACKITEM (FEEDBACK, OWNER_USERID) VALUES (?, ?)` where the values are bound by [feedbacktext, 2]. I don't see anything wrong in this statement. The id field should be populated by the JPA Identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) 
private List<Proposal> proposals;
```

Means that Proposal entities are persisted together with Group, but not merged. Other entities should be persisted separately before assigning and persisting Group entity. I would try remove this cascade attribute, and check if problem still exists.

Comment: I added the code of the Group entity and Proposal entity.
The Group also contains other objects which use the same type FeedbackItem, which have not changed during the process. Could this cause a conflict?

Comment: @Tumladhir answer replaced

Comment: You are indeed right about the cascade type. I removed it. However, It still shows the same error.
I tried creating a proposal and persisting it manually, with a cascade persist on the feedback item (since it's also a new object when the proposal is created). It's still crashing on persisting the FeedbackItem

Comment: @Tumladhir, the FeedbackItem was also new or existing? If existing, you cannot cascade persist on it.

Comment: I added the full Proposal constructor: Whenever a new proposal is created, it will create a new FeedbackItem in the constructor. This FeedbackItem will always be new, but there are existing FeedbackItem rows in the database.

Comment: @Tumladhir FeedbackItem.id is null or are you setting it to 1?

Comment: During population (SQL queries `insert into`) I'm using ID values ranging from 1-10. When creating a new FeedbackItem by code, I'm not setting any IDs. I'm expecting that the Identity generator will find the next key (11) and use that key to insert the new object.

Comment: @Tumladhir DB table should generate next id. Try to insert (using native SQL) record with null id, to check if table will generate next ID correctly. If not, primary key has wrong setup, I guess.

Comment: Oh! This actually put me on the right track. I removed all my explicit "id" values for all my objects and let the DB generate the ids. Now I can insert my new objects and they get the right PK. Apparenty the database does care about explicit id inserts and has to generate them automatically..